# Replace a word in a sentence using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

How can I replace a string like

> style="color:red;width:90%;" class="textbox"

to

> style="color:red;width:65%;" class="textbox"

using `preg_replace`?

I just want to replace "width:90%" with "width:65%" and the rest of the string should stay as it is. What regular expression should I use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace("width:90%", "width:65%", $string)
```

Comment: I can't use str_replace because the width could be any number and the unit may be '%' or 'px'.

Comment: this?: preg_replace("/width:\d+(%|px)/", "width:65%", $string)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = preg_replace("/width:90%/", "width:65%", $string);
```

if you want to make sure only elements with the class="textbox" are affected:

```
$string = preg_replace("/(style=\".+)(width:90%)(.+class=\"textbox\")/", "$1width:65%$3", $string);
```

having it work with any value and unit:

```
$string = preg_replace("/width:(\d+)(%|px)/", "width:65($2)", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot jairajs

this worked for me

```
preg_replace("/width:\d+(%|px)/", "width:65%", $string)
```

and thanks to Gerald Schneider for helping me out